# WPF chart toolkit axis scale with custom value

Tags: wpf, charts

currently I'm trying to make a chart with WPF chart toolkit,
the requirement is that Y-axis should show as the image below:
[image: Y-axis]

which describes
*0~84 is Level D
*85~99 is Level B
...

I'm not sure whether chart toolkit can make this type of Y-axis scale.
I'll try to put TextBox controls directly into the canvas for "Level *" label if above is not supported by the chart toolkit, still I have problem how can I show only 85, 100, 115 as scale of Y axis.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use a Converter for the axis label of your chart. Something like this:
XAML

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Name="chart1"  >
 <chartingToolkit:Chart.Resources>
  <HideConverter x:Key="HideConverter1" />
 </chartingToolkit:Chart.Resources>
 <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
  <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" ShowGridLines="False"  Interval="5" Minimum="0" Maximum="150" >
   <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
    <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:AxisLabel">
     <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
       <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:AxisLabel">
        <TextBlock DataContext="{TemplateBinding FormattedContent}" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource HideConverter1}}" />
       </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
    </Style>
   </chartingToolkit:LinearAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
  </chartingToolkit:LinearAxis>
 </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

and in your codebehind the converter is

```
public class HideConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // value is the current tick on the Y axis
        int x = int.Parse(value.ToString());
        switch (x)
        {
            case 85:
            case 100:
            case 115:
                return value;
            case 40: // I set 40 to be in the middle between 0 and 85
                return "Level D";
            case 90:
                return "Level C";
            case 110:
                return "Level B";
            case 130:
                return "Level A";
            default:
                return null;;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

HTH

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I've just made whole Y-axis hidden (Visibility = "Hidden") and overlap an image in parent canvas.. this case unwanted 'ticks' will not be shown in the axis.